# Using an jQuery ARRAY to feed a SELECT OPTION

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `INPUT` fields on my form which I want to collect the data input from them and store them in an `ARRAY` to then feed into a `SELECT OPTION` This is what I have so far, when it is used in the form it doesnt pick up the value from the `INPUT` boxes and the `SELECT` shows 2 empty rows, but has an ID against those rows as when I ouput the SELECT into another `INPUT` further on in my form it will show either 0 or 1.

How can I get the value input from the `INPUT` into the `SELECT`, also how can I then show the `SELECTED` option afterwards?

```
var MySelectOptions = [document.getElementById("inpbox1").value, document.getElementById("inpbox2").value];

 $.each(MySelectOptions, function(key, value) {
  $('#theselectbox').append($("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
  }));
});
```

this is how I output from the `SELECT`, I would normally use the second example, but I don't know how to get the `SELECTED` Option within the code above

```
$(function() {
    $("#theselectbox").change(function(){
        var CustomerName = document.getElementById("theselectbox").value;
        $('#customername').val(CustomerName);
    });
});
```

How I normally get the `SELECTED` Option

```
$(function() {
    $("#theselectbox").change(function(){
        var CustomerName = $('option:selected', this).attr('theselectoption');
        $('#customername').val(CustomerName);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append a new option with a value to select box as:

```
$('#theselectbox').append('<option value="'+inputValue+'">'+inputValue+'</option>');
```

And, you can show the selected option by using its **value** as:

```
$('#theselectbox').val(inputValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't understand where inputValue is coming from?

Comment: It is the value from your input fields.

Comment: I thought it was, when I added that, it gave no results on the `SELECT` so clicking on the select would show no options

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here you have the list of inputs, from which you will get values
// I will use classes, you can use ids
var inputs = ["input1", "input2"];

// The select to which you will paste the values
var sselect = $(".select-class");

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  var e = $("." + inputs[i]);
  sselect.append("<option>"+ e.val() +"</option>");
}

// Now you can just put value to select
sselect.val("selected_value");
```

How select value from input

```
<input type="text" class="js-svalue" placeholder="Select value">
```

Now js

```
var input = $(".js-svalue");
input.on("change", function(){
  sselect.val(input.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm looking at how it works now, where is this going? `sselect.val("selected_value");`

Comment: @539 The string above means the value that will be selected from javascript. You can replace "selected_value" with your own value.

Comment: to enable it to then show within my output INPUT field elsewhere on the form?

Comment: yes you can, just add some input field, and listen to change event.

Comment: Cool, ok, I've tried it and when I get to the `SELECT` it shows 2 options to select but they both say undefined and when you select either the output in another `INPUT` field shows [object Object]

Comment: @539 provide demo, i will fix.

Comment: Part 1`var inputs  = ["landregname1", "landregname2"];
var sselect = $(".ooname");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  var e = $("." + inputs[i]);
  sselect.append("<option>"+ e.val() +"</option>");
}`

Comment: Part 2 `$(function() {
    $("#owneroccuname").change(function(){
        var CustomerName = sselect.val("ooname");
        $('#customername').val(CustomerName);
    });
});`

Comment: From my code, where has it gone astray, why does it shows 2 options to select but they both say undefined and when you select either the output in another INPUT field shows [object Object]